# T-SQL Management Studio Execute SP Execution Plan - Is there a 'Max Number of Result Sets'

Tags: .net, t-sql

Is there a 'Max # of result sets that can be displayed' when executing a stored procedure & including the actual execution plan (Ctrl+M)?

The query has exceeded the maximum number of result sets that can be displayed in the Execution Plan pane. Only the first 250 result sets are displayed in the Execution Plan pane.

Thx,

Catto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to both

Not sure of limits for "results in grid" mode though (100?) "Results in Text" just keeps on displaying

Comment: Thank you gbn-- Only the first 250 result sets are displayed in the Execution Plan pane.

Answer (score 1):

Probably - but it's not configurable unless I'm mistaken.  Why in the world do you have > 250 result sets being returned?  That kind of limit exists for a reason ;-)